# Occasion wise Orders Count

Tags: sql, sql-server, set, inner-join, sql-like

```
Declare OccasionName Varchar(100)
set @OccasionName=(select distinct (Message) from OrderProducts 
where message like '%b''day%' or message like '%bday%' or Message like '%Birth%')
select Count(Distinct od.OrderID) as TotalOrders from orderdetails od
inner join (select Orderid,Message from OrderProducts) op on od.Orderid=op.OrderiD 
where od.Orderdate between '01/01/2015' and '01/05/2015' 
and op.Message like '%' + @OccasionName + '%'
and (od.TransactionId is not null) AND (od.TransactionId<>'')
```

**This is the error**:

> Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

Comment: Distinct is not function, it's a part of `select distinct` and works on the whole selected rows.

Comment: What do you not understand?  You have more than one matching messsage in `OrderProduct`.

Comment: You try to assign the result of this `(select distinct (Message) from OrderProducts 
where message like '%b''day%' or message like '%bday%' or Message like '%Birth%')` to `@OccasionName`. But seems like it gives you more than 1 row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You query seems way too complicated for what you see to want to accomplish.  I think this does what you want:

```
select Count(Distinct od.OrderID) as TotalOrders
from OrderDetails od inner join 
     OrderProducts op
     on od.Orderid = op.OrderiD 
where od.Orderdate between '2015-01-01' and '2015-05-01' and
      od.TransactionId <> '' and
      (op.message like '%b''day%' or
       op.message like '%bday%' or
       op.Message like '%Birth%'
      );
```

Notes:

- There is no need to define a variable.  The logic can go directly in the query.
- Your original problem is that multiple messages match the conditions, hence the error.
- The subquery on `OrderProducts` is superfluous.  SQL Server is smart enough to ignore it, but it could confuse other databases.
- The `is not null` condition is actually redundant when any other comparison is made on the column.
- You should use ISO (YYYY-MM-DD) or SQL Server standard (YYYYMMDD) date formats, not region specific ones.
- Lacking any information about the underlying data, you run the risk of getting a Cartesian product if "products" and "details" are independent dimensions for an `Order`.

Comment: Very detailed answer. +1 for patience.

Comment: Thank you... but i want to use this query in sp... so i need to declare variable ... @Gordon Linoff.. I have so many occasions like anniversary, wedding etc